# How I add $ in front of Input Money Format JS

Tags: javascript, html

I will like your help. I need to add the money symbol in front.

Example: `$ 45,000.00`

This code works only like this: `45,000.00`

HTML Code:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="mortgageBalance">Balance de Hipoteca:</label>
            <input style="border-radius:  10px;" name="mortgageBalance" type="text" id="mortgageBalance" class="form-control" onkeypress=" " />
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
<!-- Script for money format  -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("mortgageBalance").onblur =function (){
      this.value = parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,/g, ""))
            .toFixed(2)
            .toString()
            .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");

            document.getElementById("display").value = this.value.replace(/,/g, "")
          }
  </script>

  <!-- FINAL Script for money format  -->
```

Thanks.

Comment: I would avoid putting the `$` in the numbers because it changes the type of the data from a float to a string.  If you do put it in the input, you will have to remove it when in PHP, which is just creating more work for yourself.  If you are just displaying it you can just add it here `this.value = '$'+parseFloat`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Can you please make this like aswer. Works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add it in

```
this.value = '$'+parseFloat( ....
```

A few words of caution.  I would not add it into a field you are submitting because it will change the type of data from a float to a string, and require some work on the back end to remove the `$`.

From what I can see it looks like this is just a mortgage calculator that is displayed on the page or something like that.  But symbols like this should only be used for "display" purposes.

Don't use `"` if you are using php.  Here it's probably ok, but it's just a good practice to remember because in double quotes PHP can mistake some things for variables.

```
  $variable = "foo";
  echo "Some $variable goes here";
  echo 'Some $variable goes here';
```

Output

```
Some foo goes here
Some $variable goes here
```

Like I said it's probably ok either way but there is a big difference with how the quotes work in PHP.  It's just one of those things that if you make a habit of it, you'll avoid a whole bunch of issues later.  So if you want to display a dollar sign, it's always good to use the single quotes.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect! ;-)

Comment: sure, it was an easy one.